# Not getting extension id with Error CMN-102

Tags: ringcentral, user-presence

I continuously getting the following issue when trying call the Presence API:

```
{
  "errorCode":"CMN-102",
  "message":"Resource for parameter [extensionId] is not found",
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorCode":"CMN-102","message":"Resource for parameter [extensionId] is not found",  
      "parameterName":"extensionId"
    }
  ],
  "parameterName":"extensionId"
}
```

What will be the reason? How to fix? Finding difficult to get the extension id here.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you are not giving the correct extension id number in the API. You first need to get all the id numbers for all your extensions with this API

GET [https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~](https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/%7E/extension/%7E)

It will return a response with account id number and extension id number.

example:

```
"uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/123456789/extension/987654321";,
```

So account id number will be ***123456789*** and extension id number will be ***987654321***